# OpenVPN High Ping Latency - Windows Server/Client via UDP

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn, tcp, udp

I installed OpenVPN lately. I'm experiencing a high ping latency problem. First I was running it via TCP, now UDP but the problem does not change.

OpenVPN Server: 2.4.2
OpenVPN Client: 2.4.0
OpenVPN GUI: 11.4.0.0

Server OS: Windows Server 2016 Standard
Client OS: Windows 10 Enterprise

### Pinging the VPN Client (from VPN Server via VPN Tunnel):

```
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=1971ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=154ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=1969ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=138ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=2437ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=74ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=1976ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=60ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=55ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=128
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 10.8.0.2: bytes=32 time=39ms TTL=128
```

WinMTR statistics v0.92 GPL V2 by Appnor MSP
Loss%  | Sent | Recv | Best | Avrg | Wrst | Last |
     5 | 1677 | 1608 |   16 |  425 | 4953 | 2925 |
--> After switching from TCP to UDP the loss came down to 4% but this might come from short measuring times.

### Pinging the VPN Server (from VPN Client via VPN Tunnel):

```
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=39ms TTL=127
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=52ms TTL=127
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=40ms TTL=127
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=1938ms TTL=127
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=54ms TTL=127
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=102ms TTL=127
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=42ms TTL=127
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=39ms TTL=127
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=41ms TTL=127
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=42ms TTL=127
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=186ms TTL=127
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=183ms TTL=127
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=2464ms TTL=127
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=39ms TTL=127
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=28ms TTL=127
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=23ms TTL=127
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=38ms TTL=127
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=41ms TTL=127
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=18ms TTL=127
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=17ms TTL=127
Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=56ms TTL=127
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=40ms TTL=127
Antwort von 192.168.0.100: Bytes=32 Zeit=97ms TTL=127
```

[Yes I know the subnet is very common ;) The router doesn't allow to change this.]

WinMTR statistics v0.92 GPL V2 by Appnor MSP
Loss% | Sent | Recv | Best | Avrg | Wrst | Last |
    7 | 1500 | 1398 |   16 |  386 | 4551 |  437 |
    7 | 1503 | 1401 |   16 |  375 | 4572 | 2052 |
--> After switching from TCP to UDP the loss came down to 3% but this might come from short measuring times.

### Pinging the WAN Router in Front of the VPN Server (from VPN Client Without VPN Tunnel). The ping times from router to VPN server are permanently extremely low.

```
Antwort Bytes=32 Zeit=19ms TTL=49
Antwort Bytes=32 Zeit=20ms TTL=49
Antwort Bytes=32 Zeit=21ms TTL=49
Antwort Bytes=32 Zeit=22ms TTL=49
Antwort Bytes=32 Zeit=24ms TTL=49
Antwort Bytes=32 Zeit=22ms TTL=49
Antwort Bytes=32 Zeit=20ms TTL=49
Antwort Bytes=32 Zeit=18ms TTL=49
Antwort Bytes=32 Zeit=21ms TTL=49
Antwort Bytes=32 Zeit=23ms TTL=49
Antwort Bytes=32 Zeit=20ms TTL=49
Antwort Bytes=32 Zeit=28ms TTL=49
Antwort Bytes=32 Zeit=22ms TTL=49
Antwort Bytes=32 Zeit=21ms TTL=49
Antwort Bytes=32 Zeit=19ms TTL=49
Antwort Bytes=32 Zeit=22ms TTL=49
Antwort Bytes=32 Zeit=22ms TTL=49
Antwort Bytes=32 Zeit=20ms TTL=49
```

### Pinging Google (from VPN Server):

```
Reply bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=54
Reply bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=54
Reply bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=54
Reply bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=54
Reply bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=54
Reply bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=54
Reply bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=54
Reply bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=54
Reply bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=54
Reply bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=54
Reply bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=54
Reply bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=54
Reply bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=54
Reply bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=54
Reply bytes=32 time=73ms TTL=54
Reply bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=54
Reply bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=54
```

### VPN Server Information from "server" Logfile:

```
OpenVPN 2.4.2 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on May 11 2017
Windows version 6.2 (Windows 8 or greater) 64bit
library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017, LZO 2.10
WARNING: --ifconfig-pool-persist will not work with --duplicate-cn
NOTE: your local LAN uses the extremely common subnet address 192.168.0.x or 192.168.1.x.  Be aware that this might create routing conflicts if you connect to the VPN server from public locations such as internet cafes that use the same subnet.
Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key
Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
interactive service msg_channel=0
open_tun
TAP-WIN32 device [tap1] opened: \\.\Global\{XXX}.tap
TAP-Windows Driver Version 9.21 
Set TAP-Windows TUN subnet mode network/local/netmask = 10.8.0.0/10.8.0.1/255.255.255.0 [SUCCEEDED]
Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 10.8.0.1/255.255.255.0 on interface {XXX} [DHCP-serv: 10.8.0.254, lease-time: 31536000]
Sleeping for 10 seconds...
Successful ARP Flush on interface [6] {XXX}
do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using AF_INET6
Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
setsockopt(IPV6_V6ONLY=0)
UDPv6 link local (bound): [AF_INET6][undef]:XXX
UDPv6 link remote: [AF_UNSPEC]
MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
IFCONFIG POOL: base=10.8.0.2 size=252, ipv6=0
IFCONFIG POOL LIST
Initialization Sequence Completed

XXX TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET6]::ffff:XXX:15649, sid=33a9d389 d20384a3
XXX VERIFY OK: depth=1, XXX
XXX VERIFY OK: depth=0, XXX
XXX peer info: IV_VER=2.4.0
XXX peer info: IV_PLAT=win
XXX peer info: IV_PROTO=2
XXX peer info: IV_NCP=2
XXX peer info: IV_LZ4=1
XXX peer info: IV_LZ4v2=1
XXX peer info: IV_LZO=1
XXX peer info: IV_COMP_STUB=1
XXX peer info: IV_COMP_STUBv2=1
XXX peer info: IV_TCPNL=1
XXX peer info: IV_GUI_VER=OpenVPN_GUI_11
XXX Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
XXX [client_X] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET6]::ffff:XXX:15649
client_X/XXX MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=10.8.0.2, IPv6=(Not enabled)
client_X/XXX MULTI: Learn: 10.8.0.2 -> client_X/XXX
client_X/XXX MULTI: primary virtual IP for client_X/XXX: 10.8.0.2
client_X/XXX PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
client_X/XXX SENT CONTROL [client_X]: 'PUSH_REPLY,route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0,route-gateway 10.8.0.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.2 255.255.255.0,peer-id 0,cipher AES-256-GCM' (status=1)
client_X/XXX Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
client_X/XXX Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
```

### VPN Client Information from Connection Status:

```
OpenVPN 2.4.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Jan 31 2017
Windows version 6.2 (Windows 8 or greater) 64bit
library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017, LZO 2.09
MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1498715383,RESOLVE,,,,,,
TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]XXX:XXX
Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
UDP link local: (not bound)
UDP link remote: [AF_INET]XXX:XXX
MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1498715383,WAIT,,,,,,
MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1498715383,AUTH,,,,,,
TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]XXX:XXX, sid=7515079c 2b3869de
VERIFY OK: depth=1, XXX
Validating certificate key usage
++ Certificate has key usage  00a0, expects 00a0
VERIFY KU OK
Validating certificate extended key usage
++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
VERIFY EKU OK
VERIFY OK: depth=0, XXX
Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
[server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]XXX:XXX
MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1498715384,GET_CONFIG,,,,,,
SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0,route-gateway 10.8.0.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.2 255.255.255.0,peer-id 0,cipher AES-256-GCM'
OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
OPTIONS IMPORT: peer-id set
OPTIONS IMPORT: adjusting link_mtu to 1624
OPTIONS IMPORT: data channel crypto options modified
Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
interactive service msg_channel=552
ROUTE_GATEWAY XXX/255.255.255.0 I=15 HWADDR=XXX
open_tun
TAP-WIN32 device [Ethernet 4] opened: \\.\Global\{XXX}.tap
TAP-Windows Driver Version 9.21 
Set TAP-Windows TUN subnet mode network/local/netmask = 10.8.0.0/10.8.0.2/255.255.255.0 [SUCCEEDED]
Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 10.8.0.2/255.255.255.0 on interface {XXX} [DHCP-serv: 10.8.0.254, lease-time: 31536000]
Successful ARP Flush on interface [9] {XXX}
do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1498715384,ASSIGN_IP,,10.8.0.2,,,,
TEST ROUTES: 1/1 succeeded len=1 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1498715389,ADD_ROUTES,,,,,,
C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 192.168.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.1
Route addition via service succeeded
Initialization Sequence Completed
MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1498715389,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,10.8.0.2,XXX,XXX,,
```

### VPN Server Configuration:

```
# Which local IP address should OpenVPN
# listen on? (optional)
;local a.b.c.d

# Which TCP/UDP port should OpenVPN listen on?
# If you want to run multiple OpenVPN instances
# on the same machine, use a different port
# number for each one.  You will need to
# open up this port on your firewall.
port XXX

# TCP or UDP server?
;proto tcp
proto udp

# "dev tun" will create a routed IP tunnel,
# "dev tap" will create an ethernet tunnel.
# Use "dev tap0" if you are ethernet bridging
# and have precreated a tap0 virtual interface
# and bridged it with your ethernet interface.
# If you want to control access policies
# over the VPN, you must create firewall
# rules for the the TUN/TAP interface.
# On non-Windows systems, you can give
# an explicit unit number, such as tun0.
# On Windows, use "dev-node" for this.
# On most systems, the VPN will not function
# unless you partially or fully disable
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
;dev tap
dev tun

# Windows needs the TAP-Win32 adapter name
# from the Network Connections panel if you
# have more than one.  On XP SP2 or higher,
# you may need to selectively disable the
# Windows firewall for the TAP adapter.
# Non-Windows systems usually don't need this.
dev-node tap1

# SSL/TLS root certificate (ca), certificate
# (cert), and private key (key).  Each client
# and the server must have their own cert and
# key file.  The server and all clients will
# use the same ca file.
#
# See the "easy-rsa" directory for a series
# of scripts for generating RSA certificates
# and private keys.  Remember to use
# a unique Common Name for the server
# and each of the client certificates.
#
# Any X509 key management system can be used.
# OpenVPN can also use a PKCS #12 formatted key file
# (see "pkcs12" directive in man page).
ca "C:\\XXX\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\XXX\\server.crt"
key "C:\\XXX\\server.key" # This file should be kept secret

# Diffie hellman parameters.
# Generate your own with:
#   openssl dhparam -out dh2048.pem 2048
dh "C:\\XXX\\dh2048.pem"

# Network topology
# Should be subnet (addressing via IP)
# unless Windows clients v2.0.9 and lower have to
# be supported (then net30, i.e. a /30 per client)
# Defaults to net30 (not recommended)
topology subnet

# Configure server mode and supply a VPN subnet
# for OpenVPN to draw client addresses from.
# The server will take 10.8.0.1 for itself,
# the rest will be made available to clients.
# Each client will be able to reach the server
# on 10.8.0.1. Comment this line out if you are
# ethernet bridging. See the man page for more info.
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

# Maintain a record of client <-> virtual IP address
# associations in this file.  If OpenVPN goes down or
# is restarted, reconnecting clients can be assigned
# the same virtual IP address from the pool that was
# previously assigned.
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

# Configure server mode for ethernet bridging.
# You must first use your OS's bridging capability
# to bridge the TAP interface with the ethernet
# NIC interface.  Then you must manually set the
# IP/netmask on the bridge interface, here we
# assume 10.8.0.4/255.255.255.0.  Finally we
# must set aside an IP range in this subnet
# (start=10.8.0.50 end=10.8.0.100) to allocate
# to connecting clients.  Leave this line commented
# out unless you are ethernet bridging.
;server-bridge 10.8.0.4 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.50 10.8.0.100

# Configure server mode for ethernet bridging
# using a DHCP-proxy, where clients talk
# to the OpenVPN server-side DHCP server
# to receive their IP address allocation
# and DNS server addresses.  You must first use
# your OS's bridging capability to bridge the TAP
# interface with the ethernet NIC interface.
# Note: this mode only works on clients (such as
# Windows), where the client-side TAP adapter is
# bound to a DHCP client.
;server-bridge

# Push routes to the client to allow it
# to reach other private subnets behind
# the server.  Remember that these
# private subnets will also need
# to know to route the OpenVPN client
# address pool (10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0)
# back to the OpenVPN server.
;push "route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0"
;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"

# To assign specific IP addresses to specific
# clients or if a connecting client has a private
# subnet behind it that should also have VPN access,
# use the subdirectory "ccd" for client-specific
# configuration files (see man page for more info).

# EXAMPLE: Suppose the client
# having the certificate common name "Thelonious"
# also has a small subnet behind his connecting
# machine, such as 192.168.40.128/255.255.255.248.
# First, uncomment out these lines:
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
# Then create a file ccd/Thelonious with this line:
#   iroute 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248
# This will allow Thelonious' private subnet to
# access the VPN.  This example will only work
# if you are routing, not bridging, i.e. you are
# using "dev tun" and "server" directives.

# EXAMPLE: Suppose you want to give
# Thelonious a fixed VPN IP address of 10.9.0.1.
# First uncomment out these lines:
;client-config-dir ccd
;route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.252
# Then add this line to ccd/Thelonious:
#   ifconfig-push 10.9.0.1 10.9.0.2

# Suppose that you want to enable different
# firewall access policies for different groups
# of clients.  There are two methods:
# (1) Run multiple OpenVPN daemons, one for each
#     group, and firewall the TUN/TAP interface
#     for each group/daemon appropriately.
# (2) (Advanced) Create a script to dynamically
#     modify the firewall in response to access
#     from different clients.  See man
#     page for more info on learn-address script.
;learn-address ./script

# If enabled, this directive will configure
# all clients to redirect their default
# network gateway through the VPN, causing
# all IP traffic such as web browsing and
# and DNS lookups to go through the VPN
# (The OpenVPN server machine may need to NAT
# or bridge the TUN/TAP interface to the internet
# in order for this to work properly).
;push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

# Certain Windows-specific network settings
# can be pushed to clients, such as DNS
# or WINS server addresses.  CAVEAT:
# http://openvpn.net/faq.html#dhcpcaveats
# The addresses below refer to the public
# DNS servers provided by opendns.com.
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"

# Uncomment this directive to allow different
# clients to be able to "see" each other.
# By default, clients will only see the server.
# To force clients to only see the server, you
# will also need to appropriately firewall the
# server's TUN/TAP interface.
client-to-client

# Uncomment this directive if multiple clients
# might connect with the same certificate/key
# files or common names.  This is recommended
# only for testing purposes.  For production use,
# each client should have its own certificate/key
# pair.
#
# IF YOU HAVE NOT GENERATED INDIVIDUAL
# CERTIFICATE/KEY PAIRS FOR EACH CLIENT,
# EACH HAVING ITS OWN UNIQUE "COMMON NAME",
# UNCOMMENT THIS LINE OUT.
duplicate-cn

# The keepalive directive causes ping-like
# messages to be sent back and forth over
# the link so that each side knows when
# the other side has gone down.
# Ping every 10 seconds, assume that remote
# peer is down if no ping received during
# a 120 second time period.
keepalive 10 120

# For extra security beyond that provided
# by SSL/TLS, create an "HMAC firewall"
# to help block DoS attacks and UDP port flooding.
#
# Generate with:
#   openvpn --genkey --secret ta.key
#
# The server and each client must have
# a copy of this key.
# The second parameter should be '0'
# on the server and '1' on the clients.
tls-auth "C:\\XXX\\ta.key" 0 # This file is secret
key-direction 0

# Select a cryptographic cipher.
# This config item must be copied to
# the client config file as well.
# Note that 2.4 client/server will automatically
# negotiate AES-256-GCM in TLS mode.
# See also the ncp-cipher option in the manpage
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256

# Enable compression on the VPN link and push the
# option to the client (2.4+ only, for earlier
# versions see below)
;compress lz4-v2
;push "compress lz4-v2"

# For compression compatible with older clients use comp-lzo
# If you enable it here, you must also
# enable it in the client config file.
;comp-lzo

# The maximum number of concurrently connected
# clients we want to allow.
max-clients 10

# It's a good idea to reduce the OpenVPN
# daemon's privileges after initialization.
#
# You can uncomment this out on
# non-Windows systems.
;user nobody
;group nobody

# The persist options will try to avoid
# accessing certain resources on restart
# that may no longer be accessible because
# of the privilege downgrade.
persist-key
persist-tun

# Output a short status file showing
# current connections, truncated
# and rewritten every minute.
status openvpn-status.log

# By default, log messages will go to the syslog (or
# on Windows, if running as a service, they will go to
# the "\Program Files\OpenVPN\log" directory).
# Use log or log-append to override this default.
# "log" will truncate the log file on OpenVPN startup,
# while "log-append" will append to it.  Use one
# or the other (but not both).
;log         openvpn.log
;log-append  openvpn.log

# Set the appropriate level of log
# file verbosity.
#
# 0 is silent, except for fatal errors
# 4 is reasonable for general usage
# 5 and 6 can help to debug connection problems
# 9 is extremely verbose
verb 3

# Silence repeating messages.  At most 20
# sequential messages of the same message
# category will be output to the log.
;mute 20

# Notify the client that when the server restarts so it
# can automatically reconnect.
;explicit-exit-notify 1
```

### VPN Client Configuration:

```
# Specify that we are a client and that we
# will be pulling certain config file directives
# from the server.
client

# Use the same setting as you are using on
# the server.
# On most systems, the VPN will not function
# unless you partially or fully disable
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
;dev tap
dev tun

# Windows needs the TAP-Win32 adapter name
# from the Network Connections panel
# if you have more than one.  On XP SP2,
# you may need to disable the firewall
# for the TAP adapter.
;dev-node MyTap

# Are we connecting to a TCP or
# UDP server?  Use the same setting as
# on the server.
;proto tcp
proto udp

# The hostname/IP and port of the server.
# You can have multiple remote entries
# to load balance between the servers.
remote XXX XXX
;remote my-server-2 1194

# Choose a random host from the remote
# list for load-balancing.  Otherwise
# try hosts in the order specified.
;remote-random

# Keep trying indefinitely to resolve the
# host name of the OpenVPN server.  Very useful
# on machines which are not permanently connected
# to the internet such as laptops.
resolv-retry infinite

# Most clients don't need to bind to
# a specific local port number.
nobind

# Downgrade privileges after initialization (non-Windows only)
;user nobody
;group nobody

# Try to preserve some state across restarts.
persist-key
persist-tun

# If you are connecting through an
# HTTP proxy to reach the actual OpenVPN
# server, put the proxy server/IP and
# port number here.  See the man page
# if your proxy server requires
# authentication.
;http-proxy-retry # retry on connection failures
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port #]

# Wireless networks often produce a lot
# of duplicate packets.  Set this flag
# to silence duplicate packet warnings.
;mute-replay-warnings

# SSL/TLS parms.
# See the server config file for more
# description.  It's best to use
# a separate .crt/.key file pair
# for each client.  A single ca
# file can be used for all clients.
;ca ca.crt
;cert client.crt
;key client.key

# Verify server certificate by checking that the
# certicate has the correct key usage set.
# This is an important precaution to protect against
# a potential attack discussed here:
#  http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm
#
# To use this feature, you will need to generate
# your server certificates with the keyUsage set to
#   digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
# and the extendedKeyUsage to
#   serverAuth
# EasyRSA can do this for you.
remote-cert-tls server

# If a tls-auth key is used on the server
# then every client must also have the key.
;tls-auth ta.key 1
key-direction 1

# Select a cryptographic cipher.
# If the cipher option is used on the server
# then you must also specify it here.
# Note that 2.4 client/server will automatically
# negotiate AES-256-GCM in TLS mode.
# See also the ncp-cipher option in the manpage
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256

# Enable compression on the VPN link.
# Don't enable this unless it is also
# enabled in the server config file.
#comp-lzo

# Set log file verbosity.
verb 3

# Silence repeating messages
;mute 20

<ca>XXX</ca>
<cert>XXX</cert>
<key>XXX</key>
<tls-auth>XXX</tls-auth>
```

### VPN Server Network Config (NIC):

**card1**
*IPv4:*
IP: 192.168.0.100
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateways: 192.168.0.1, 10.8.0.1
DNS: fromISP1, 192.168.0.100, fromISP2, fromISP3, fromISP4, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
WINS: None

*IPv6:* Deactivated

**card2**
*IPv4:*
IP: 192.168.0.102
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateways: None
DNS: fromISP1, 192.168.0.100, fromISP2, fromISP3, fromISP4, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
WINS: None

IPv6: Deactivated

**tap1**
*IPv4:*
DHCP Enabled
Default Gateways: None
DNS: 192.168.0.100
WINS: None

*IPv6:* Deactivated

Comment: TCP-in-TCP is a sure-fire recipe for horrible performance. I'd recommend that you do a root-cause look into why UDP isn't working and then fix that.

Comment: To add to @EEAA's comments, the dropped packets from using OpenVPN also seems a bit suspicious. That loss rate of 5-7% seems very high to me. I'm not sure I've even seen 1% loss on a working OpenVPN connection when bridging two sites via a VPN server located at a third site.

Comment: @EEAA: I switched from using TCP to using UDP. Unfortunately the problem persists.

Comment: @lungj: The connection works and I can use RDP via the tunnel (TCP and UDP). But there is still (UDP) a loss of 3-4% and this is a terrible user experience. Suspicious yes, and what can I do?

Comment: I added the network interface config. Maybe this gives a hint?

Comment: @Sailcomp Did you figure out how to solve this problem? Facing the exact same situation.